# Avoid repeated information when having multiple joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query that uses joins to join multiple tables

```
select DISTINCT
        tblArticles.Article_Title, 
        tblArticles.Article_img,
        tblArticles.Article_Content,
        tblArticles.Article_Date_Created,
        tblArticles.Article_Sequence,
        tblWriters.Writer_Name,
        tblTypes.Article_Type_Name, 
        tblimages.image_path as "Extra images"

from tblArticles inner join tblWriters
on tblArticles.Writer_ID_Fkey = tblWriters.Writer_ID inner join
tblArticleType on tblArticles.Article_ID = tblArticleType.Article_ID_Fkey inner join
tblTypes on tblArticleType.Article_Type_ID_Fkey = tblTypes.Article_Type_ID left outer join tblExtraImages
on tblArticles.Article_ID = tblExtraImages.Article_ID_Fkey left outer join tblimages
on tblExtraImages.image_id_fkey = tblimages.image_id

order by tblArticles.Article_Sequence, tblArticles.Article_Date_Created;
```

And I get the following results:

[image]

If an article has more than one type_name then I will get repeated columns for the rest of the records. Is there another way of joining these tables that would prevent that from happening?

Comment: You could not select type_name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to just remove column `Article_Type_Name` from the select clause. This allows `SELECT DISTINCT` to identify the rows as duplicates, and eliminate them.

Another option is to use an aggregation function on the column. In recent SQL Server versions, `STRING_AGG()` comes handy (you can also use `MIN()` or `MAX()`):

```
select
    tblArticles.Article_Title, 
    tblArticles.Article_img,
    tblArticles.Article_Content,
    tblArticles.Article_Date_Created,
    tblArticles.Article_Sequence,
    tblWriters.Writer_Name,
    string_agg(tblTypes.Article_Type_Name, ',') 
        within group(order by tblTypes.Article_Type_Name) Article_Type_Name_List, 
    tblimages.image_path as Extra_Images
from ..
group by
    tblArticles.Article_Title, 
    tblArticles.Article_img,
    tblArticles.Article_Content,
    tblArticles.Article_Date_Created,
    tblArticles.Article_Sequence,
    tblWriters.Writer_Name,
    tblimages.image_path
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing here is a Cartesian product; you've joined Tables in such a way that multiple rows from one side match with rows from the other

If you don't care about the article_type, then group the other columns and take the max(article_type), or omit it in a subquery that selects distinct records, not including the article type column, from the table that contains article type). If your SQLS  is recent enough and you want to know all the article types you could STRING_AGG them into a csv list

Ultimately what you choose to do depends on what you want them for; filter the rows out, or group them down